# Where to put the ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel that can be use in the Controllers, View, and Core. The Core is a seperate project while the Controllers and View is in the Web Project. Where is the best location to put the ViewModel, is it in the Web project or in the Core, or do I need to created a seperate project for the View Model only?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a viewmodel that can be use in the Controllers, View, and Core.

No. You are not using it in the Core. Google "Separation of Concerns". The responsibility of the view model is to represent the Model (the Core project) in the view. It should not be used for anything else. I've written about view models here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/three-reasons-to-why-you-should-use-view-models/

*It's the controllers responsibility to take everything from the Model (core 
 project) and create an appropriate view model.*

Putting the view model somewhere so it can be used in the Core gives it more than one reason to change which will break the Single Responsibility Principle (one of the five SOLID principles). What it means is that several parts of your application will be affected by every change that you make and it will likely lead to small workarounds or quick fixes which will give you a maintenance nightmare in a year of so.

**Update**

Example using AutoMapper:

```
public class FlairController
{
    public FlairController(IYourServiceOrRepository repos)
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        SomeCoreObject entity = _repos.Get(id);
        FlairViewModel model = new FlairViewModel();
        Mapper.Map(entity, model);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Your example code (in the comment) is how the method would look like without a mapping framework.

Comment: Here is my Project Structure
Website - Views
Controllers- all controllers are here (confuse if I will put it here)
Core- contains Auto Mapper configuration, Mapper class, ModelView mapping, and Services (ViewModel are using here to return the data I need)
DataAccess- Repository classes
Model- generated by EF

Comment: The view models and the automapper configuratiosn between view models and the Core models should be placed in the UI (MVC3 project), since the Core should not be aware of anything in the UI layer. Your services should not use view models as they are specialized to display HTML

Comment: can you please put it here a sample codes regarding the approach that you've mentioned, actually I am very confuse now, because as what I am thinking of what your saying is, your controller has this sample code  return View(
                view,
                new FlairViewModel 
                {
                    Dinners = dinners.ToList(),
                    LocationName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(location.City) ? "you" :  String.Format("{0}, {1}", location.City, location.RegionName)
                }
            );

Comment: and in the view you have this Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FlairViewModel>"

Comment: I don't want my controller to behave just like that. it highly appreciated if send me some codes regarding your implementation.:)

Comment: I see so the mapping is in the controller, but this also working even if my controllers is in seperate project?

Comment: Don't split up the MVC pattern over multiple projects. The controllers belong in the same project as the views since they are used as a glue between the Model and the View.

Answer (score 0):

The view model is typically a wrapper around the model that has the UI formatted data. You should probably keep your model class in the Core project and the view model class in your web project.

The constructor for your View Model class can take an instance of your model class (and any other objects you need to populate your view) and generate the proper view data. For example, if you model has a DateTime object, then your view model could have a corresponding String property that contains the DateTime in the format you want to show.

Comment: so how can I use the view model in the core? Do I need to reference the web project class?

Comment: The other way around. The web project references your core project. I've updated my answer

Comment: Well, I am confuse now, because I used an automapper to map the ViewModel and the Model. If I instantiate the Model in the constructor, it seems that I don't need the Automapper?

Comment: The auto mapper is another option. I was just providing one option.

Answer (score 0):

Since ViewModels are specific to the Views, I would usually create a ViewModel folder under my UI project and keep it there.

[image]

I will create a seperate Service Layer ( another project) for bridging data between my ViewModels and Entity Models. My Controller Action methods call the service layer with the ViewModel object.

Comment: Actually we have the same design, can you please send me a sample code of your service layer and controller that returns a ViewModel? For me to understand correctly.